# How to get plot attributes in Plots.jl

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

How can I access the attributes of a plot after creating it?

For example, I was hoping to get the y-axis limits from a plot. Something like this didn't work:

```
p1 = Plots.plot(rand(10))
get(p1,:ylim)
```

This errors:

```
MethodError: no method matching get(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Symbol)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plots are organized into subplots (often just one) which are organized into series. In this case you want the y axis limits, which is a function of the subplot. Normally you can get a named attribute (e.g. `y`) from the first series in the first subplot by

```
p1[1][1][:y]
```

In the case of limits it's a little more complicated, they are properties of `Axis` which are owned by the subplot. But luckily you can just do

```
ylims(p1)
```